# Other than death, what are the potential long-term health impacts on individuals infected with COVID-19?

Tags: covid-19, side-effects, virus, disease, sars-cov-2

There is a lot of concern about deaths resulting from or exacerbated by SARS-CoV-2 infections, but I can find little about the potential long-term health impacts on those who 'recover' (understandably, I suppose).

Some articles have touched on health impacts including reduced lung function, brain damage and organ damage. Is there a list of such impacts, how long people might suffer them and other such information? It seems to me the case fatality rate is just part of the picture.

Comment: There are manys such lists. We require questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research here, so what has your research revealed so far?

Comment: @CareyGregory Solely that damage _can_ be caused to the lungs, kidneys, heart and brain. Nothing about whether it is damage that will heal over time and how long a time or respective proportions of people who suffer / will suffer in such respects; little detail about what kind of damage.